# Problem with my dockerfile when I try to RUN

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, airflow

I would like to create an image from my dockerfile to create a container containing :

- airflow
- spark

in order to create an airflow pipeline that would launch a Spark job. The purpose of the Spark job will be to retrieve a large amount of csv files from a GCP bucket and process them.

So I tried to create my Dockerfile and create the image. However I get an error.

Here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.5.0

ARG SPARK_VERSION="3.1.2"
ARG HADOOP_VERSION="3.2"

# setup spark
ENV SPARK_HOME /usr/local/spark
RUN cd "/tmp" && \
    wget --no-verbose "https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz" && \
    tar -xvzf "spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz" && \
    mkdir -p "${SPARK_HOME}/bin" && \
    mkdir -p "${SPARK_HOME}/assembly/target/scala-2.12/jars" && \
    cp -a "spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}/bin/." "${SPARK_HOME}/bin/" && \
    cp -a "spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}/jars/." "${SPARK_HOME}/assembly/target/scala-2.12/jars/" && \
    rm "spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz"
```

And here the error (**exit code 127**):

```
docker build -t my_airflow_image .
[+] Building 0.3s (5/5) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                            
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 795B                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/apache/airflow:2.5.0                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/apache/airflow:2.5.0                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => ERROR [2/2] RUN cd "/tmp" &&     wget --no-verbose "https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.1.2/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz" &&     tar -xvzf "spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz" &&     mkdi  0.2s
------
 > [2/2] RUN cd "/tmp" &&     wget --no-verbose "https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.1.2/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz" &&     tar -xvzf "spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz" &&     mkdir -p "/usr/local/spark/bin" &&     mkdir -p "/usr/local/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.12/jars" &&     cp -a "spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/bin/." "/usr/local/spark/bin/" &&     cp -a "spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/." "/usr/local/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.12/jars/" &&     rm "spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz":
#5 0.227 /bin/bash: line 1: wget: command not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/bash -o pipefail -o errexit -o nounset -o nolog -c cd "/tmp" &&     wget --no-verbose "https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz" &&     tar -xvzf "spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz" &&     mkdir -p "${SPARK_HOME}/bin" &&     mkdir -p "${SPARK_HOME}/assembly/target/scala-2.12/jars" &&     cp -a "spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}/bin/." "${SPARK_HOME}/bin/" &&     cp -a "spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}/jars/." "${SPARK_HOME}/assembly/target/scala-2.12/jars/" &&     rm "spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz"]: exit code: 127
```

Can you help me to resolve it please ?

Moreover, do I have to add Python in the container or it is not necessary because with airflow we code in Python?

Thank you by advance

Comment: `ARG`s reset at each build stage, so `ARG` needs to appear after the `FROM` line of each build stage that uses it.  If your setup only contains a single build stage it should be enough to move the existing `ARG` lines after `FROM`.

Comment: thank you I updated the topic with a new error

Comment: it says wget not found. add a command in dockerfile ```RUN apt-get install wget``` to install it and then try

Comment: I got this error :
[2/3] RUN apt-get install wget:
#5 0.253 E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
#5 0.253 E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
------
executor failed running [/bin/bash -o pipefail -o errexit -o nounset -o nolog -c apt-get install wget]: exit code: 100

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN yum install wget

RUN apt-get install wget
```

Depending on your flavor of Linux.  You're getting the error because wget does not exist in your container.  You need to install it first.

Comment: Hello I tried your solution and I got this :
------
 > [2/4] RUN yum install wget:
#5 0.220 /bin/bash: line 1: yum: command not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/bash -o pipefail -o errexit -o nounset -o nolog -c yum install wget]: exit code: 127

Comment: What version of Linux are you using?  If you're on Ubuntu use RUN apt-get install wget